# In h5py what is type "|V15060"

Tags: python, h5py

I am trying to read and h5py file, there are multiple datasets in it and I am able to read these easily but there is one in which i am facing one problem with the datatype as `<HDF5 dataset "word_key": shape (1,), type "|V15060">` and its tuple (`dataset[0][0]`, `dataset[0][1]`).

Problem: I am only interested in `dataset[0][1]` which contains a list of word and while reading I am only getting 7 characters for each word not more than that. Say the data has `['elephant','umbrella']` my code is reading `['elephan','umbrell']`. Here is my code, any solution regarding how to change the read block size.

## the code

```
with h5py.File('C:/dataset.h5','r') as hdf:
    data=hdf.get('word_key') 
    print(data)
    dataset=np.array(data)[0][1]
    word_dic={}
    for val, word in enumerate(dataset[0][1],0):
        if len(word.decode('UTF-8'))==7: 
               print(word.decode('UTF-8'))
        word_dic[val]=word.decode('UTF-8')
```

Comment: What's the `shape` and `dtype` of `data[0]`?

Comment: Have you tried to view the contents with HDFView? Frequently this is the quickest way to understand what you have. Also doesn't your length filter for those with 7 characters?

Comment: The shape of data[0] is () and type is <class 'numpy.void'>.

Comment: Yes, I have tried HDFView but while opening this specific dataset the program crashes and terminates

Comment: @Saqib Sohail, hmmm, well, that's not a good sign. Have you tried the h5dump tool from the HDF Group? It's a command line utility. Maybe it will help you see what you have. You can also try the pytables module (instead of h5py). They have a command line tool (ptdump), as well as a Python API.

Comment: What's the output of `h5py.check_dtype(vlen=data.dtype)`?